# Starting another activity using Android Intent

Tags: android

I am new to Android development, I was just going through the training here: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html

I have just wrote the code in Eclipse as is on the page; it's supposed to initiate another activity and should display the message which I typed in the text box of the current activity.

But I am getting an error while running the installed App on the AVD. The error message is

"Unfortunately *my app* is stopped"

LogCat last 10 lines are as below :

```
06-06 15:14:22.958: W/ActivityManager(1226): Unbind failed: could not find connection for android.os.BinderProxy@b346b948
06-06 15:14:22.978: D/dalvikvm(1535): GC_CONCURRENT freed 459K, 19% free 2445K/3012K, paused 29ms+5ms, total 177ms
06-06 15:14:23.509: W/Trace(1226): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
06-06 15:14:23.509: W/Trace(1226): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
06-06 15:14:26.278: W/Trace(1226): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
06-06 15:14:26.298: W/Trace(1226): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
06-06 15:14:32.988: W/Trace(1451): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
06-06 15:14:33.004: W/Trace(1451): Unexpected value from nativeGetEnabledTags: 0
```

There are lot more entries in LogCat which I don't think I can copy here. Can anyone please let me know how to figure out the exceptions or errors from this file?

I do not know how to find where the code has gone wrong or throwing exception.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: please post your logcat output

Comment: Please post your error message it would be better to solve.

Comment: You should read up on how to use the android DDMS(Dalvik Debug Monitor Server) <- http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/ddms.html -> This will show you any Log messages and a strack trace for any crashes. In eclipse you can find the DDMS by going to Window/Open Perspective/Other/DDMS and you can add the Logcat window to your workspace by going to Window/Show View/Other/Android/Logcat.

Answer (score 2):

Probably you didn't add your second activity to AndroidManifest.xml of your project.

First do this in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<activity name=".ActivityB" />
```

Then in first Activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityB.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation, there are two activities,MainAcivity DisplayMessageActivity.

So declare the MainActivity in manifest

```
     <application>
       .......

     <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:noHistory="true"

        android:label="@string/app_name">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
```

```
   android:name=".DisplayMessageActivity"
   ......//documentation
```

Answer (score 0):

Try out this code in your class file:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Activity.this, Activity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Register your activity in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<activity android:name="<Package>.Activity" >
</activity>
```

Comment: Thank you all for the suggestions,But since I am using Eclipse  these two activities are already exists in AndroidManifest.xml .